# detonation and deflagration in supernovae

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, explosions, supernova

I'm reading about supernovae processes. The article mentions that there are these two processes in combustion, detonation and deflagration. The article goes on to state that the fact that a wide variety of elements appear in supernovae suggests that deflagration is the main process, and this is where I'm confused.

I understand that detonation is more violent, but would it really incinerate almost everything? And why does deflagration eject instead of incinerating? Why can't there be a mix of detonation and deflagration?

What exactly is the difference between detonation and deflagration in supernovae?

[How to Blow Up a Star article](http://www.if.ufrj.br/~orca/intcosmo/122/Hillebrandt_SciAm_295_42_2006_How_to_blow_up_a_star.pdf)

The only things I know about detonation and deflagration come from this article.

Comment: I suggest linking the article in question to improve the chances of anyone being able to answer in context.  That said, normal definitions of detonation and deflagration are chemical processes and do not represent the consumption of elements.  Burning and explosions use up chemical compounds, but not their constituent elements and would create no change in the chemical make-up of the elements present.  The processes might however represent a different distribution in the results.  It would take nuclear effects to actually change the elemental composition.

Comment: I think the terms are used in the supernova to differentiate between subsonic thermal transfer and supersonic shock transfer of energy.

Comment: @dlb the supernova community uses the same terms for nuclear burning.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between deflagration and detonation in flows other than supernovae?

Comment: In explosives, "detonation" refers to a supersonic combustion wave whereas "deflagration" is a slow (subsonic) combustion.